# Is is possible to disable this warning in clang? warning: #pragma once in main file

Tags: clang, pragma, suppress-warnings

warning: #pragma once in main file

We're running our headers through clang to get a partial AST.

Is it possible to disable that warning?

Answer (score 12):

Use the `-Wno-pragma-once-outside-header` command line argument. Consult the Clang documentation [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wpragma-once-outside-header).

Comment: warning: unknown warning option '-Wno-pragma-once-outside-header'

Answer (score 10):

I had this thing when I accidentally included a header file in compile sources (this header has #pragma once line). To fix this remove header from compile sources (and probably you need to replace it with .cpp file)

Comment: This was the issue I had because I was using $^ in my makefile as a shortcut.

Answer (score 5):

There's no `-W` option for "#pragma once in main file", so you can't turn it off via the usual means. (However, the Clang developers are very aware that warnings without `-W` options suck, and there's a general rule that *new* warnings *always* get `-W` options. Cleaning up the *old* code, unfortunately, is left as an exercise for frustrated users.)

If you don't mind shell hackery, you could always do something like this:

```
# This gives the warning...
clang -c myheader.h

# ...This doesn't.
echo '#include "myheader.h"' | clang -c -x c++-header -o myheader.h.gch -
```

The trailing `-`, as usual, means "read from stdin". The `-x c++` tells Clang what language you're using (since it can't tell from the file extension when there *is* no file), and changing `c++` to `c++-header` means that we want to produce a .gch file instead of an .o file.

The two `.gch` files thus produced are **NOT** bit-for-bit identical. I don't know enough about gch files to tell you what might be observably different about their behavior. However, since all you care about is Clang's AST, I bet you'll be fine with it. :)

Answer (score -1):

Use the `-w` (lowercase `w` not uppercase `W`) option while compiling the source to suppress such warnings.

Comment: Bad, that flag turns off *all* warnings.

Answer (score -3):

There are no option to control it, so just ban this warning in your code.